# Using AUCTEX inside orgmode

Tags: auctex

Is it possible to use AUCTEX inside orgmode? Orgmode is fantastic but writing LaTeX code is not so easy. Is it possible to combine these two worlds?

Comment: Aloha. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an Emacs specific question, you rather should ask it at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

There are two possibilities that came into my mind:

1. Use AUCTeX within `org-babel`, see https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html
2. Write the complete document in `org-mode` and export/publish it to LaTeX, see section *LaTeX export* in the Org mode manual and at https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-export.html

Comment: Aloha. The second suggestion seems to be contrary to what the OP is trying to achieve, which is the ease of LaTeX-ing that AUCTEX facilitates, within Org mode. See? Agree?